# How do I compare SQL Server databases and update another?

Tags: sql-server

I am currently dealing with a scenario of whereby I have 2 SQL databases and I need to compare the changes in data in each of the tables in the 2 databases. The databases have the same exact tables between them however may have differing data in each of them. The first hurdle I have is how do I compare the data sets and the second challenge I have is once I have identified the differences how do I say for example update data missing in database 2 that may have existed in 1.

Comment: Is this user data or static data, i.e., could you just wipe the table in the one database and copy over the table from the other periodically?

Comment: @mellamokb - When you say user data, what do you mean exactly? The data in database 1 is generally updated dynamically via a web interface however considering it is offsite, we need to be able to update the same database internally which I would consider static. The reason I would to be able to identify the changes as opposed to simply wiping the database and writing into it again is because we need to pass only the changes into a third database.

Comment: Is this only a one time thing or will it need to be repeated?

Comment: @Shawn Melton - It will be repeated on a regular basis hence am looking for something robust

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use SQL Data Compare instead of re-inventing the wheel? It does exactly what you're asking - compares two databases and writes scripts that will sync in either direction. I work for a vendor that competes with some of their tools and it's still the one I would recommend.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/

Comment: SQL Data compare and SQL Compare from Redgate are excellent products.  I use them both on a regular basis, and they have saved me hundreds of hours when deploying code, or merging data.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand - Looks like an excellent product however are there free alternatives?

Comment: There probably are, and a simple web search would bear those out, but I've never tried any of them. Maybe someone else is using a free alternative and can comment.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey Please read this blog post, it tries to elaborate on what "free" really means. I also list over 20 alternatives to Red Gate's schema compare tool, some of them free, and surely many of those also support data comparison (though I haven't inspected the list recently - the blog post is from 2009). http://bertrandaaron.wordpress.com/2012/04/20/re-blog-the-cost-of-reinventing-the-wheel/

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand - Would you know anything about Single Sign On, Federated Servers, etc? Be extremely grateful if I could drop you an email with questions as no one seems to be able to answer the questions I have, even the ones I have posted here.

Comment: Sorry, no, I probably wouldn't be too useful there.

Answer (score 2):

One powerful command for comparing data is [**`EXCEPT`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx).  With this, you can compare two tables with same structure simply by doing the following:

```
SELECT * FROM Database1.dbo.Table
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM Database2.dbo.Table
```

This will give you all the rows that exist in Database1 but not in Database2, including rows that exist in both but are different (because it compares every column).  Then you can reverse the order of the queries to check the other direction.

Once you have identified the differences, you can use `INSERT` or `UPDATE` to transfer the changes from one side to the other.  For example, assuming you have a primary key field `PK`, and new rows only come into Database2, you might do something like:

```
INSERT INTO Database1.dbo.Table
SELECT T2.*
FROM Database2.dbo.Table T2
LEFT JOIN Database1.dbo.Table T1 on T2.PK = T1.PK
WHERE T1.PK IS NULL -- insert rows that didn't match, i.e., are new
```

The actual methods used depend on how the two tables are related together, how you can identify matching rows, and what the sources of changes might be.

Comment: Thanks. As there databases are significantly large, how fast would the queries be as speed is also of the essence? Secondly, is there a way I could compare a list of tables as opposed to a single table at a time?

Comment: The queries can only be as fast as the scans required to read all of the data. There isn't any magic I'm aware of that can make it faster than this. Hopefully this isn't the kind of task you're doing every day or in a situation where it matters whether it takes 2 minutes or 5 minutes...

Comment: You could potentially use `bcp` to get the data moved from one server to the other really quickly as a data dump in a temp table.  Then do the actual updates locally from the temp table to the live table.  But @AaronBertrand's answer is overall a much better suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You also can look at the Data Compare feature in Visual Studio 2010 (Premium and higher)? I use it to make sure configuration tables in all my environments ( i.e. development, test and production ) are in sync. It made my life enormously easier. 
You can select tables you want to compare, you can choose columns to compare. What I haven't learned to do though is how to save my selections for the future use.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with SQL Compare which is a great too for development but if you want to do this on a scheduled basis a better solution might be Simego's Data Sync Studio. I know it can do about 100m (30 cols wide) row compare on 16GB on an i3 iMac (bootcamp). In reality it is comfortable with 1m -> 20m rows on each side. It uses a column storage engine.

In this scenario it would only take a couple of minutes to download, install and test the scenario.

I hope this helps as I always look for the question mark to work out what someone is asking.